# Is there an algebra group or ring in which computing the inverse element is hard without some trapdoor information?

Tags: group-theory

Specifically, I want an algebra group $G$ (or ring $R$) features:

1. Given elements $g,h\in G$ (or $R$ ), computing $g\cdot h \in G$ (or $R$ ) is easy.
2. Given an element $g \in G$  (or $R$ ), finding the inverse of $g$ is hard.
3. Given an element $g \in G$ (or $R$ ) and a trapdoor $\tau$, finding the inverse of $g$ is easy, s.t. $g\cdot g^{-1}=1_e$.

**Remark 1.** Due to the property of ring, $g\in R$ does not have correpsonding inverse. Even so, I still expect an approximate way to present the multiplication inverse of $g$ in Ring, or at least *partial elements* in Ring have multiplication "inverses"!

**Remark 2.**"easy" means the computation can be done in polynomial time, even if the group is very large, e.g., $|G|= 2^{256}$; On the contrary, "hard" means the computation cannot be done in polynomial time, if the group is very large.

I investigated traditional RSA, braid, and ECC groups, no such group can meet the above requirements.

The conjugacy problem in the braid group is that: Given $x,y$, where $y=a\cdot x \cdot a ^{-1}$, finding such $a$ is hard. Although, the problem does not meet my requirement, i.e., given $g$, finding $g^{-1}$ is hard, I tried to convert the conjugacy problem as below:

IF we have $x,a$ s.t. $y=a\cdot x \cdot a ^{-1}$, THEN $y\cdot y^{-1}=a\cdot x \cdot a ^{-1}\cdot y^{-1}=(a\cdot x)\cdot(a ^{-1}\cdot y^{-1})=1_e$; in which case, we let $g:=(a\cdot x), g^{-1}:=(a ^{-1}\cdot y^{-1})$, the new problem is that given such $g$, whether computing $g^{-1}$ is hard in braid group.

(But I think it is easy to compute, intuitively, due to we can multiply $g$ itself to find the inverse in $O(N)$ complexity where $N$ is $ord(G)$)

So, back to my question, does this kind of group (or ring) exist?

Comment: Define "easy" and "hard". If you are dealing with a finite group then first of all this can be reduced to cyclic group. And here there's a trivial algorithm for finding $g^{-1}$: just multiply $g$ by itself. Eventually you will reach $g^{-1}$. Which can be optimized via euclidean algorithm. And this definitely can be efficiently calculated even for huge orders.

Comment: @freakish I added the explaination of "easy" and "hard" in my question. Without knowing any auxiliary information, one can only obtain $(g \in G, G, ord(G))$ to try to compute the inverse $g^{-1}$. The methods you mentioned, such as extented euclidean algorithm, are indeed helpful to compute the inverse efficiently.  If such group I desired does not exist, can the ring satisfy my requirements?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether this is a group or ring. As long as it is finite you still look only at $\{g^n\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, which has to be finite. In case of ring it is slightly more difficult since $g$ does not have to be invertible. But you can catch this situation as well through the same method. And this brute force approach is linear in complexity. In other words: calculating inverses is not hard. At least compared to prime factorization or discrete logarithm kind of problems.

Comment: Any answer depends greatly on how your group is given. For example, if you have a group given in terms of generators $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ then finding an inverse in easy - if $g=x_{i_1}^{j_1}\cdots x_{i_k}^{j_k}$ then $g^{-1}=x_{i_k}^{-j_k}\cdots x_{i_1}^{-j_1}$, which is linear in $|g|=\sum_{l=1}^k|j_l|$. These generators may be matrices or permutations, or your group may be given by generators and relations (i.e. by a group presentation), and here verifying if a word over the generators is the inverse of $g$ is undecidable in general.

Comment: @user1729 Thank you for your comment. I have no idea that how to express the presentation of elements in this kind of group or ring.  I just want to look up this kind of group or ring. In your comment, I am confused about the meaning of the last sentence, specially  " if a word over the generators is the inverse of g
 is undecidable in general". So, could you explain the sentence more concretely? Thanks!

Comment: @freakish I have modified my question, could you give me further suggestions about my question. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @mingalex Look up "the word problem for groups". My sentence is just an application of that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an open problem. In [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/463), it was stated that

> Groups of infeasible inversion. Hohenberger [[Hoh03](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/463.pdf#cite.Hoh03)] and Molnar [[Mol03](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/463.pdf#cite.Mol03)] considered groups of infeasible inversion, on which it is hard to compute the inverse of a random group element, and showed that such a group is useful for constructing directed transitive signature. Irrer etal. [[ILOP04](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/463.pdf#cite.ILOP04)] showed that such a group is also useful for constructing broadcast encryption. However, there have been no known instantiations for such a group until very recently Altug and Chen [[AC18](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/463.pdf#cite.AC18)] proposed a candidate instantiation based on a new computational problem related to isogenies of elliptic curves over unknown characteristic rings.
>
> A group of infeasible inversion can be seen as a special case of our notion of inversion-hard ring where we only consider multiplications and do not consider additions.3 There is still no candidate construction of an inversion-hard ring (except for the obfuscation-based one given in [Appendix A](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/463.pdf#appendix.A)).

A few remarks:

- Property 2 needs to be made more clear that $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is hard on average (or in the worst case), as there are always some element whose inverse is easy to find (e.g. the identity element of a group or a ring, or any element of small order if exist).
- Property 3 can be easily satisfied (without further constraint), the "trapdoor" for computing $g^{-1}$ can simply be the order $n$ of $g$ (in $G$ or in the case of rings $R^{\times}$), as we can compute $g^{-1}=g^{n-1}$ efficiently through [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Moreover, the order $|G|$ (resp. $|R^{\times}|$) of $G$ (resp. $R^{\times}$) can serve as a universal trapdoor for all $g$ (But this might be too much, as in the case of RSA, knowing $|(\mathbb Z/pq\mathbb Z)^{\times}|$ will break the encryption scheme).
- As mentioned in the comment, since this is a complexity issue instead of information one, the presentation of the group matters. In particular, if we can find any such an example $G$, we may take a cyclic subgroup generated by $g\in G$, and almost surely the inverse problem on $\langle g \rangle $ is hard, so $G$ can be probably assumed to be cyclic. [The cited paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/463.pdf) considers the case where the ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, but with a special presentation (which is only assumed, not constructed except a conditional construction in Appendix A), $p$ is hidden. [The candidate solution](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/926) was only conjectured to work.
- The construction in Appendix A is based on VBB obfuscation which may not exist, even though [iO obfuscation](https://www.quantamagazine.org/computer-scientists-achieve-crown-jewel-of-cryptography-20201110/) has been done. But I didn't dive into the details of all the subtleties.